# Webpack ignores stats option

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

**UPDATE**

@Daniel Khoroshko's answer fixed my stats problem. For future reference, there are (at least) 4 ways webpack can handle stats:

1. Treat `stats` as a regular webpack option https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/
2. If using `devServer`, it must be placed in that object (see note in link above)
3. If using the Node API, it must be in a callback function. https://webpack.js.org/api/node/#stats-object
4. As Daniel pointed out, `webpack-dev-middleware` overrides stats so the object must be in there https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware#stats

================================================

Using webpack 3.10 I'm trying to suppress the million `extract-text-webpack-plugin` logs I'm getting.

We are using the webpack Node API. In our `server.js`, our node entry point, we have this:

```
// server.js

const app = express();

if (environment.isLocal) {
  require('./webpackConfig')(app);
} else {
  app.use(compression());
}
// other stuff
```

Where we use webpack with node:

```
// webpackConfig.js

const webpack = require('webpack');
const config = require('../webpack.config.dev');

module.exports = (app) => {
  const compiler = webpack(config, (err, stats) => {
    stats.toJson("none"); // none for brevity, but not working
  });

  app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
    noInfo: true,
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath
  }));

  app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler));
};
```

Finally, the entire config

```
// webpack.config.dev.js

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  entry: {
    app: [
      'eventsource-polyfill',
      'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
      './src/index'
    ]
  },
  target: 'web',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './src'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name]-[hash].css'),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'annoying webpack', 
      template: './src/index.html', 
      alwaysWriteToDisk: true,
      inject: false
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackHarddiskPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
        options: {
          failOnWarning: false,
          failOnError: false
        },
        exclude: /node_modules|dist/
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: [path.join(__dirname, 'src')]
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Output in console

```
webpack building...
webpack built c22fd3ae797ecd55eccc in 7410ms
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Hash: c22fd3ae797ecd55eccc
Version: webpack 3.10.0
Time: 7410ms
                       Asset       Size  Chunks                    
Chunk Names
                      app.js    2.53 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  
app
app-c22fd3ae797ecd55eccc.css     125 kB       0  [emitted]         
app
                  app.js.map    2.97 MB       0  [emitted]         
app
app-c22fd3ae797ecd55eccc.css.map    4.71 kB       0  [emitted]         
app
                  index.html  275 bytes          [emitted]
   [3] ./node_modules/react/react.js 56 bytes {0} {0} [built]
 [100] ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js 59 bytes {0} {0} [built]
 [107] ./node_modules/react-redux/es/index.js 230 bytes {0} {0} 
[built]
   ..... 
    + 867 hidden modules
    Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
         Asset    Size  Chunks  Chunk Names
    index.html  568 kB       0
    .....   
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
webpack built d7509fff9f1c995bf5ee in 7523ms
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Hash: d7509fff9f1c995bf5ee
Version: webpack 3.10.0
Time: 7523ms
                       Asset       Size  Chunks                    
Chunk Names
                      app.js    2.53 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  
app
app-d7509fff9f1c995bf5ee.css     125 kB       0  [emitted]         
app
                  app.js.map    2.97 MB       0  [emitted]         
app
app-d7509fff9f1c995bf5ee.css.map    4.71 kB       0  [emitted]         
app
                  index.html  275 bytes          [emitted]
   [5] ./src/App.js 3.62 kB [built]
   [6] ./src/store/configureStore.js 325 bytes [built]
   .....
    + 867 hidden modules
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     Asset    Size  Chunks  Chunk Names
index.html  568 kB       0
   [0] ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.html 646 bytes {0} [built]
   [1] ./node_modules/lodash/lodash.js 540 kB {0} [built]
   [2] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
   [3] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 517 bytes {0} [built]
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding stats options `webpack-dev-middleware` and `webpack-dev-server` have their own stats setting, which I suppose overrides webpack own setting. I would suggest trying this

```
  app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
    noInfo: true,
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
    stats: 'errors-only'
  }));
```

Comment: unfortunately I don't know why it builds twice :-(

Comment: Thank you so much for the stats fix!!! That worked. I'm going to edit my question to highlight that fix.

Comment: hi, I'm glad it works. speaking about double building - if you were to add `console.log('test')` into your webpack config file, just after imports, will it print it twice?

Comment: I'm actually not sure what I changed, but it's no longer building twice. I essentially started over from our previous webpack config and it came together. Thanks again for the help